# Can you test for a player whose score does *not* equal a given number in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, is it possible to test for a player whose score does *not* equal, say, 5 (i.e. if their score is less than 5, greater than 5, or null)?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank Fair point, and the answer is no, as I had absolutely no idea where to start. That said, is this the place to discuss this, where I've already accepted an answer?

Comment: Whether you've accepted an answer or not is irrelevant.  We like to see *effort*.  You're displaying none, and it's not really fair to us to expect us to help without any on your end.

Comment: @Frank Please go back and read my comment again. I agreed to everything you said. My only point was whether this particular question was the one on which to raise the point.

Comment: Which question it's commented on doesn't really matter, either.  The point is to help you understand, and hopefully make an effort for next time.

Comment: I think this was a very clear question for a particular problem. And not everyone can come up with a solution to it by himself. So I think this is definitely a valid question.

Comment: @DonielF I updated my answer to 1.13/1.14, it's now much easier to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big edit to this answer, because 1.13 added a way to directly do this:

```
/execute as @a unless score @s <score> matches <value> run <command>
```

Comment: What's it do with a null test?

Comment: 2 works as well with null, for 1 I added notes about having no score. You can add 0 for everyone, but then it shows everyone if the scoreboard is visible. So 2 is the only variant with no downsides (except that you have a tag more in your list).

Comment: Oh, I understood that's what you meant. What I was curious about was how the simpler case fails. (I have never played with scripting in Minecraft.)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. You could use 2 commands, one to test if the score is lower and one to test if the score is higher. But this doesn't work for "null".

Instead, I usually just test if the score **is** 5 and invert the signal using scoreboard tags (or a comparator + redstone torch).

An example:

`/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!not5] add not5`

`/scoreboard players tag @a[score_objectiveName_min=5,score_objectiveName=5] remove not5`

Only players who don't have a score of 5 for `objectiveName` will have the `not5` tag

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't consider having no score in my first answer. Going to change it. Do you want to cooperate on an answer, since our two answers are almost identical?

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of **1.13 execute commands** this can be done without going through tags.

In the OP's question the answer would be as simple as

```
execute as @p unless entity @s[scores={myScore=5}] run tellraw @s ["Not 5!"]
```

This will run the tellraw when myScore is not 5, this includes myScore having values like 0 or 1 as well as myScore being unset/null.